# call functions on a uiwebview controller outside the Viewcontroller class in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a uiwebview in my ios program and it is connected to a variable inside the ViewController interface

```
@interface ViewController() <UIWebViewDelegate>  
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *uiwebview;  
@end
```

I want to call functions on this uiwebview from outside the viewcontroller

For example, I can control the webview just fine if it is used between

```
@implementation ViewController  

.  
.  
.  

@end
```

But I want to use it somewhere outside. For example, I want to do something like this

```
[uiwebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

from outside `@implementation ViewController`

What are the options to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

> But I want to use it somewhere outside. For example, I want to do something like this
>
> ```
> [uiwebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
> ```
>
> from outside `@implementation ViewController`

Stop wanting that. An IBOutlet should be private to its own view controller. If you want other view controllers to be able to do something to that web view, then arm your ViewController with public methods that they can call.

Comment: If I make a public function inside the view controller [such as `+(void)eternalControl{...` ] then it stops detecting the `uiwebview` inside this public function. If I make a private function, [such as `-(void)eternalControl{...` ], it detects the `uiwebview` inside the function but the function itself is not detected outside the ViewController. What is a good approach to control the `uiwebview` from somewhere outside the ViewController? What I really need to do is update the `uiwebview` from inside a C-style function, ...

Comment: ...and buy reading questions around here I have found that C style functions are not considered part of the ViewController even if they are declared inside the ViewController

Comment: I don't know what you mean by any of that. I didn't say to make a C-style function. I said to make a public method. I stand by my answer.

Comment: isn't adding a + before a function definition the way to make it public? If I do that it stops allowing me to use `uiwebview` inside the public function.

Comment: No, `+` has nothing to do with the public status of something in Objective-C. I've got a free online book that teaches you Objective-C; maybe you could benefit from reading it. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_messages_and_methods_2

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do, I have an app that has various tabs some of which are web view. When my app starts I get it to pre-load the web views so that when the tabs are selected they are already loaded. Its important the the other tabs are all singleton classes so that there is only one instance of them.

In my main ViewController viewDidLoad I have this ..

```
//Pre load calculators and status page
EvolutionViewController *evoCalc = [EvolutionViewController sharedInstance];
[evoCalc.view layoutSubviews];

IVCalcViewController *ivCalc = [IVCalcViewController sharedInstance];
[ivCalc.view layoutSubviews];

StatusViewController *serverStatus = [StatusViewController sharedInstance];
[serverStatus.view layoutSubviews];
```

Those instantiate the classes for the other tabs which also loads up the web views associated with those classes. All the classes are similar this is the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EvolutionViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>


+ (EvolutionViewController *) sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

And the .m

```
#import "EvolutionViewController.h"

@interface EvolutionViewController ()

@end

@implementation EvolutionViewController

@synthesize webView;

#pragma mark - Singleton Methods
static EvolutionViewController *_sharedInstance;

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

+ (EvolutionViewController *) sharedInstance
{
    return _sharedInstance;
}


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    if (!_sharedInstance) {
        if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
            _sharedInstance = self;
        }
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}


#pragma mark - View Controller Methods

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"evo_calc" withExtension:@"html"];
    NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

}

@end
```

Mine uses local html resources but works the same with a proper URL as well.